# how to access the id of textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have to acces the id of textarea in javasript.Please tell me how we can access the id of the textarea in javascript.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(document.getElementById("urtextboxId").id);
```

Comment: Shortened: `alert("urtextboxId")` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access ids of all textarea in your document you can use this

```
var txtAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var len = txtAreas.length;
var ids = new Array();

for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    ids.push(txtAreas[i].id);    
}
```

Comment: Too much `$.each()` I take it. ;)